# Subfloor and Batten Construction of 1950s Hardwood Floor

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, subfloor

Recently purchased a 1950s cape cod style home with hardwood floors throughout. They squeak terribly everywhere in the home. As I got ready to tackle this problem with glue and screws through the subfloor from the basement I noticed that the floor is actually is made up of these layers:

- Hardwood floor boards
- 3/4" Battens that appear to lay inline with the joists
- Brown Paper (presumably to cut down on dust)
- 3/4" Plank Subfloor
- Joists

Given that extra 3/4" space between the subfloor and the hardwoord finish floor, no glueing or screwing will help my squeaks, but I was more stunned by the construction. Is this a common method in the 50s or any other time? My understanding is that battens would typically be used to aid in installing hardwood floor over a concrete slab, where you have no joists to work with, rather than over joists and a subfloor.

(Another oddity is that there are few runs of conduit in the 3/4" space between the subfloor and the finish floor. Why the heck would you do this when you have a full basement below???)

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, the interior finished floor (the hardwood floor boards) essentially float 3/4" above the subfloor, supported only by 3/4" furring strips on top of each joist? What's the spacing of the joists/furring strips?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, that's correct. Joist spacing is 16"

Comment: That is... odd... I haven't a clue. Hang on until the more experienced carpenters show up with some suggestions.

Comment: The 3/4" battens will be there specifically and exclusively to make room for the conduit; I have heard of that in houses before. It is an easy way to rewire areas when redoing floors without having to cut open walls, which is a big headache, especially if they are plaster and lathe. Be glad they at least ran conduit, or it would not be to code and you'd have to pull any electrical wiring up and route it elsewhere. Do you know if the conduit has anything in it currently?

Comment: To answer why not run them in the basement: because they don't want wires in their (expected to be, if it isn't currently) finished basement, of course...

Comment: Basement is not finished and there are lots of other conduit runs that are exposed.

Comment: Then I would remove the conduit in the subfloor and re run any wiring in them through the basement, personally.

Comment: the brown paper is most likely a vapor barrier that prevent's moisture from being absorbed by the under-side of the floor boards. The sub-floor is 5 inch planks? are they run diagonal to the joists?

Comment: Its not clear what your question is or the problem you are trying to solve. Is it the squeeky boards, why construct it this way or why there is conduit under the floor?

Comment: @IamOnStage The question is why construct it this way.

Comment: @ojait Planks are 9 1/2" and run perpendicular to the joists.

Comment: I've heard of people doing this for noise reasons and to promote springiness

Comment: Adding for posterity: I owned a 1920's greystone (a two-flat) where the hardwood floors were installed this way. The subfloor was boards about 5" laid perpendicular to the joists. It also had paper-y sheet material between the subfloor and battens (possibly tarpaper, though I never made a positive ID). They were not obviously different to stand or walk on vs others with "typical" installation. That may have been helped by or because their condition was incredibly good for their age — they had obviously been lightly used and well cared for, with the original finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation is not typical unless those are intended as sleepers (used to correct out of level joists) or furring (used to raise the plane of a surface in order to flush with the plane of adjacent finishes). In the first case, you would still be missing a layer of sheathing above the sleepers as sub floor. In the second case, underlayment should have been full coverage. As you are discovering, what they've done leads to issues for a typical lumber flooring plank spanning across a typical joist layout.

Some quick points:

- It would be impractical to fix this in any other way than to live with it or pull it up  and relay your floor properly.
- The brown paper is probably kraft paper for a little moisture resistance from the basement humidity. Most likely, whoever installed this was cutting costs and willing to live with the consequences. Without sub floor to support the paper, it's a miracle they could lay it at all.
- There is no reason to run electrical between flooring and subfloor.

---

Since your Plan A didn't work, maybe this could be your plan B:

You might try finding any nails that are sitting on the side of a joist, which squeak from rubbing under normal circumstances as you walk across the floor, and any nails that are sticking out from the side of the joist, which squeak under normal circumstances from the inadequate withdrawal resistance. You can try pulling them through with a pair of end cutters.

Other than that, try adding a picture to your post and maybe it will allow for a solution as the description you've given is currently explained.